# styles of an angular plugin (ng-daterangepicker) cannot be changed

Tags: css, angular, npm, sass

I installed that angular2 plugin called "ng-daterangepicker" , then I wanted to resize a div inside it, I changed the .sass file but nothing changes on my browser (I cleared the cache but still not working) , I think that I should modify .scss files but I found none on the plugin, I found just plain sass files.

```
.calendar-container
      display: inline-block
      width: 330px
      height: 100%
      padding: 20px
      border-right: 1px solid $border-light
      float: left
```

I changed the width from 340px to 330px, but on the browser I still find that 340px.
here is the strange part : I deleted the .sass file but everything is still working, so I think that maybe the component gets its styles from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, it's a bad idea to change the source code of a plugin. In case you update the component or reinstall the project, every custom change you added to that specific plugin will be discarded.

What you can do instead is to add a CSS class to the directive like so:

```
<!-- app.component.html -->
<ng-daterangepicker class="myCustomDateRange" [(ngModel)]="value" [options]="options"></ng-daterangepicker>
```

and then point to the element you need and add custom CSS for it in one of your SCSS files.

```
<!-- someStylesFile.scss -->
.myCustomDateRange .ng-daterangepicker .calendar .calendar-container { width: 330px; }
```

Comment: You're welcome. The other issue you pointed, in the future, when you update/delete files from `node_modules` or `bower_components` folders, you need to restart the server in order to detect the changes. Your server only detects changes in the files of your application and not in the files from the plugins.

Comment: yes that's true, I saw that lite-server doesnt detect changes on node-modules plugins